# Боковая панель перекрывает текст вопроса

Tags: дефект, дизайн

Хотел бы спросить, одного у меня сейчас наблюдается такая проблема? Зашел на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1054430/) прочитать, ну и там бокова панель перекрыла текст вопроса, и чтобы дочитать текст мне пришлось убирать его через инспектор.
Размер моего монитора `1600x900`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я тоже видел такое, но в другом вопросе. А сейчас эффект пропал

Comment: @avp Только что зашел проверил, также.. Странное поведение))

Comment: Я думаю, что надо указать размер экрана Вашего девайса. И браузер.

Comment: @Дмытрык Добавил

Comment: @Дмытрык, Firefox 70.0.1 yandex 1.1 экран 1920x1080 27"